# Sorting WooCommerce Products by Distance

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a WooCommerce multi vendor site and need to be able to sort the products by distance from the site visitor.

- I have latitude and longitude values stored against each product in the catalogue.
- I know the latitude and longitude of the visitor
- I know the formula to calculate the distance between the two

My thought is to add an alias field to the products returned by WooCommerce, potentially using the woocommerce_product_query hook that contains the distance from the site visitor and then sorting on that alias field. I know how to do this in SQL, E.g. something along the lines of:

SELECT *, {FORMULA FOR CALCULATING DISTANCE} AS distance FROM {TABLE} SORT BY distance;

but I cannot figure out how to add this alias field to the returned fields using the hooks provided by WooCommerce.

Has anyone had any experience in achieving this or something similar? Or perhaps I am approaching it from the wrong angle!

If so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out with quite a bit of help from this article:

https://xplus3.net/2010/08/08/filtering-on-a-non-standard-database-field-with-wordpress/

To add an extra alias field to WP_Query you need to hook into posts_fields which allows you to modify the SELECT part of the query being made, e.g.

```
function my_posts_fields( $fields, $query ) {
    $userlat = {Users Lat};
    $userlong = {Users Long};
    $destlat = {Destination Lat};
    $destlong = {Destination Long};

    $fields .= sprintf(",( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( %f ) ) * cos( radians( %f ) ) * cos( radians( %f ) - radians( %f ) ) + sin( radians( %f ) ) * sin( radians( ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations.latitude ) ) ) ) ) AS distance", $destlong, $userlat, $destlat, $destlong, $userlong, $userlat, $destlat);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('posts_fields', 'my_posts_fields', 10, 2);
```

Then to sort on this new field you need to hook into posts_orderby which allows you to modify the ORDER BY part of the query, e.g.

```
function my_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
  $orderby = "distance ASC";
  return $orderby;
}

add_filter('posts_join', 'my_posts_join', 10, 2);
```

You will need to add some code to only apply the fields to the post types that you want it to be applied to, but the gist is as above.